# GCC documentation of this type of declaration int(a)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

The idea of my program was to create a local variable and that way constructor is called. When the variable was going out of scope then the destructor would be called. All the work was done in Ctor and Dtor.
Basically I wanted to create a local variable that I do not really care about and have it destroyed automatically.

Then I would do something like this :

```
typedef Foo DoInCtor
```

After that I would do something like this :

```
DoInCtor()
```

That would create that local var that I do not actually care about.

This is something similar to what I was working on :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class Bar
{
public :
  Bar() {printf("BAR, Default Ctor %p\n", this);}

  ~Bar() {printf("BAR, Default Dtor %p\n", this);}
};

class Foo
{
public :
  Bar m_bar;
  Foo() : m_bar(Bar()) {printf("FOO, Default Ctor %p\n", this);}
  Foo(Bar ref_bar) : m_bar(ref_bar) {printf("FOO, Other Ctor %p", this);}
  ~Foo() {printf("FOO, Default Dtor %p\n", this);}
};

Foo foo;

int main()
{
  Bar bar1;
  printf("bar1 address, outside local scope : %p\n", &bar1);
  std::cout << "Type of bar1 : " << typeid(bar1).name() << std::endl;
  // This is some lcoal scope
  {
    Foo(bar1);
    printf("bar1 address, in local scope : %p\n", &bar1);
    std::cout << "Type of bar1 : " << typeid(bar1).name() << std::endl;
  }
  Foo foo1= Foo(bar1);
  printf("foo1 address, in local scope : %p\n", &foo1);
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs the following on my machine, compiled with g++ 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04  :

```
BAR, Default Ctor 0x6021f1
FOO, Default Ctor 0x6021f1
BAR, Default Ctor 0x7ffe6808cfcd
bar1 address, outside local scope : 0x7ffe6808cfcd
Type of bar1 : 3Bar
BAR, Default Ctor 0x7ffe6808cfcf
FOO, Default Ctor 0x7ffe6808cfcf
bar1 address, in local scope : 0x7ffe6808cfcf
Type of bar1 : 3Foo
FOO, Default Dtor 0x7ffe6808cfcf
BAR, Default Dtor 0x7ffe6808cfcf
FOO, Other Ctor 0x7ffe6808cfceBAR, Default Dtor 0x7ffe6808cfcf
foo1 address, in local scope : 0x7ffe6808cfce
FOO, Default Dtor 0x7ffe6808cfce
BAR, Default Dtor 0x7ffe6808cfce
BAR, Default Dtor 0x7ffe6808cfcd
FOO, Default Dtor 0x6021f1
BAR, Default Dtor 0x6021f1
```

What bothers me is that in main function scope `bar1` is a `Bar` type, but in local scope it is `Foo` type.
It seems to me that this is some type of var declaration.
I even tried following on gcc :

```
int(a)
```

and it created a variable `a` which is `int` type.

The question here is if somebody can provide me with some kind of documentation where this is explained in detail. Some GCC or some other documentation.

Comment: And why the C tag?

Comment: This is just standard C++. You are allowed to put parentheses around the identifier in a declaration. Is that all you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was asking, if this is standard.
I just wanted to know if there is any documentattion about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just create a local variable, called `bar1` which overrides the one from `main` and has the type `Foo`. You do not create a temporary `Foo` variable with the second constructor. And it is allowed to have the name in parenthesis in this case.

The suspicious line is identical to `Foo bar1;`